# finding fullname, firstname or lastname only

Tags: java, mysql

please help, i have a small java + mysql project. its a searching program for names of people. i got a search box which you can input the name and a 'GO' button to execute. 
i can search:

```
santiago,martin <--- in this format. my problem is i cant search the following formats:

santiago  <-- input only lastname
 santiago <-- input with space before the lastname.
```

here's my code. please enlighten me. i know my code is not good. or any suggestion to make this more efficient.

```
String memberToFind = inSearchBar.getText();
    String[] memberToFindParts = memberToFind.split("\\,");
    String memberName0 = memberToFindParts[0];
    String memberName1 = memberToFindParts[1];
    int namelength = memberToFindParts.length;

    if(namelength!=0){
        String sql = "SELECT (accountNo) AS 'Account No',"
        + "(lastname)AS 'Lastname',"
        + "(firstname)AS 'Firstname'"
        + "FROM cmje.membertable "
        + "WHERE   ((accountno)LIKE '%"+memberName0+"%' OR "
                + " (accountno)LIKE '%"+memberName1+"%' OR "
                + " (lastname)LIKE '%"+memberName0+"%' OR "
                + " (lastname)LIKE '%"+memberName1+"%' OR "
                + " (firstname)LIKE '%"+memberName0+"%' OR "
                + " (firstname)LIKE '%"+memberName1+"%')"
                + " ORDER BY lastname DESC;";           

        try{
                pst = sqlconn.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                masterListTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    }
    }else if(namelength==0){
        String sql = "SELECT (accountNo) AS 'Account No',"
        + "(lastname)AS 'Lastname',"
        + "(firstname)AS 'Firstname'"
        + "FROM cmje.membertable "
        + "WHERE   ((accountno)LIKE '%"+memberToFind+"%' OR "
                + " (lastname)LIKE '%"+memberToFind+"%' OR "
                + " (firstname)LIKE '%"+memberToFind+"%')"
                + " ORDER BY lastname DESC;";


        try{
                pst = sqlconn.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                masterListTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Please describe the specific problem.

Comment: Just side note: You are not making proper use of Prepared Statement.

Comment: I don't know the equivalent in Java but you can trim the input to get rid of empty spaces.

Comment: Your code is kind of vulnerable to SQL injections, you should use parameters in the statement and set them properly, instead of concatenating the string.

Comment: hello guys thank you for your fast reply. @sotirios my problem is i can't search if user only inputs lastname or firstname only.

Comment: @smit thanks for suggesting to use trim.

Comment: @gamb i will read all about sql injection. thank you for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> santiago <-- input with space before the lastname.

You can easily solve this making this change:

```
String memberToFind = inSearchBar.getText().trim();
```

> santiago  <-- input only lastname

You should implement more than one search mode according to the number of `memberToFindParts`. As you can't know if the user's input is the firstname or the lastname I think you'll have to show both results:

```
String[] memberToFindParts = memberToFind.split("\\,");
if(memberToFindParts.length == 2) {
    /*
     * search by fullname
     */
} else if(memberToFindParts == 1) { // Note currently you have namelenght==0 here and that's wrong
    /*
     * search by firstname and lastname separately
     */
} else {
    // input unexpected (0 or more than 2 words)
}
```

Comment: additional note :  i didn't use the .split(), im currently using replacAll("\\s","")

Answer (score 0):

You have to trim the input String:

```
String memberToFind = inSearchBar.getText().trim();
```

Comment: thanks stan for answering.